# Link to an app in the App Store before approved?

Tags: iphone, app-store

From what I understand, you have to use the appname when linking which is the slug that apple generates.  So, for an app like like 'Guns and Weapons Encyclopedia' the slug will be 'guns-and-weapons-encyclopedia' or it can be 'guns-weapons-encyclopedia'

So one doesn't know in advance what the name will be -- only after Apple approves and processes the app for the store.

Is there a way to generate a reliable link before the app is approved?

Thanks

Comment: You might like [the App Stores proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores) on Area 51.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can use the app ID to generate the link. You get the ID when you register an app in the iTunes portal.

You want a link like this:

`http://itunes.apple.com/app/idAAAAAAAAA`

Where, `AAAAAAAAA` is your app id.

Comment: I'm not sure. There should be documentation somewhere, let me look.

Comment: I haven't found documentation, but that seems to be the case. See the [iTunes Link maker](http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker), which does split links up by country.

Comment: It's a tough choice, let's see... :)

Comment: if you use the link in the app on the device it will open the "App Store" app and it will use the users app market.

Answer (score 0):

There is also one other way:

Use "appstore.com" scheme.

Your app name is "Houston, we have an issue!" you can transform it into:

(iOS) http://www.appstore.com/houstonwehaveanissue

(Mac) http://www.appstore.com/mac/houstonwehaveanissue

Rules:

1. lower case characters
2. strip whitespaces
3. "!¡"#$%'()*+,-./:;<=>¿?@[]^_`{|}~" characters that have to be removed

More detailed description can be found at:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1633/_index.html (Creating easy-to-read short links to the App Store for your apps and company)